# How can we use paypal payflow to split the amount

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, payflowpro, payflowlink

How can we use Payflow to split the amount I have got from a transaction made by the user. ie, Customer paid $10 for an item. I need to take $2 and send the rest to the merchant. Is it possible in Paypal Express Checkout? How can we do it with Payflow Pro?

Any helps will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) to accomplish this.